# Sum Gridview column with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a GridView with 100 records and the page size of the grid is 10. Also I need to sum a column from the gridview and show it in a label. I am using the below code in page load event to sum the gridview column and it works as expected.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < gvDetails.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
   sum += Int.Parse(gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
}
lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

This code sums the whole value, I mean the sum of 100 records. But I would need a sum only for the 10 records where each page will hold only 10 records and when I do paging and move to each page it has to show only the sum of that respective page.

To make simple I just need to sum the column values I see in the grid and not for all records.

How can this be achieved? Please suggest me.

Comment: There are a ton of similar questions asking for the same thing on SO.  Have you checked any of them?

Comment: @Yuck - Yes I checked all of 'em and haven't found anything close, so ended up posting here with anticipation.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with JQuery on document ready? The GridView renders as a HTML Table, you can loop the cells of a column and increment as you do so till you get the total, then append that to label..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GridView_RowDataBound, execute for each page in the gridview.

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Please expand it a bit [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PageIndex` and `PageSize` to get current gridview page index and page size respectively and apply logic to get set of required rows in current page and loop over the required rows to get sum. Following is some code snippet to get the required number of rows in current page.

```
int pageidx = gvDetails.PageIndex;
int pagesize = gvDetails.PageSize;
int startidx = pageidx * pagesize;
int endidx = startidx + pagesize;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = startidx; i < endidx; i++)
{
    sum += Int.Parse(gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
}
lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: But I am not able to bind the result to a label which is outside the gridview.

Comment: @Michael, My solution has included simple calculation this, that has nothing to do with setting `lblTotal.Text` and this part is same as yours too! . Please debug through the application see whether `sum` has correct value.

Comment: @Arindham Nayak - Sum has correct value,but the problem is the column sum of the respective page is not getting binded to the label each time I do paging.

Comment: @Michael, ok if sum is correct, then the original problem is solved, but regarding label binding, if that is out of grid, then it should work..

Comment: @Arindham Nayak - Yes, the label is outside grid and its not binding values to the label.

Comment: @Michhael , As per your original question, it was working, but here i havn't changed anything regarding to that. If you are facing that issue with original question, you should put up one more question for that.